# Absolute convergence of the series $sin(a_n)$ implies...?

Tags: calculus

Can someone please give me a counterexample for the following statement?

If $\sum _1 ^\infty sin(a_n) $ absolutely converges , then $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ also absolutely converges.

I tried working with $a_n = \frac{ (-1)^n } {n} $ and $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n lnn}{n}$ , but without any success...

Got any idea?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You might want to use the fact that it is possible for $\sin(a) = \sin(b)$ but for $ a \ne b$.

Comment: If $a_n=\pi$, then $\sin a_n=0$, and thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin a_n$ converges absolutely, while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=(-1)^nn\pi$. Then $sin(a_n)=0$ for all $n$ which gives the first sum as 0 however, the second sum isn't quite as computable as $a_n$ doesn't converge to a finite value.

Note that in this case the sequence $a_n$ doesn't even converge as one could take sub-sequences that converge to various values.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n=\pi$, then $\sin a_n=0$, and thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin a_n$ converges absolutely, while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not.

Hence, you need to make an assumption: $a_n\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Then use the fact that
$$
\frac{2|x|}{\pi}\le|\sin x|\le |x|,
$$
for all $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, which implies that:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\,\,\text{converges absolutely}\,\,\,\Longleftrightarrow
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin a_n\,\,\,\text{converges absolutely}.
$$